# A word to describe an individual who takes the blame for a team's collective failure

Tags: single-word-requests

Example: The soccer team lost the match because the strikers failed to score on a regular basis. However, the coach took the blame for the failure.

In the above example what word can be used to describe the coach who takes the blame for the team's failure?

I searched for the correct word but couldn't find an appropriate one. A word that I found was Fall Guy. But it seems, a fall guy would be one who is falsely accused  for something that has gone wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This person  is called a ***scapegoat***.

According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scapegoated:

: one that bears the blame for others

Comment: "Judas goat" is a variant.

Comment: The connotation of *scapegoat* is one who *others* blame, however, regardless of whether that party accepts responsibility or not.